# Why is my build failing with jax-ws maven plugin?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, maven

I am new to web services and so am currently building a Hello World type program that I can deploy locally to Tomcat. However, I am currently experiencing issues when trying to generate domain classes based on my XML schema.

My XSD schemais as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/helloworld" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/helloworld"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="request" type="tns:requestType">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="requestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:element name="response" type="tns:responseType">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="responseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


</schema>
```

And my jax-ws plugin within my pom.xml is configured like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>xsd/*.xsd</include>
                <include>schema/*/*.xsd</include>
            </schemaIncludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

However, I am currently experience the following build error:

```
[INFO] Failed to parse a schema.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.947s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 18 11:04:37 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (default) on project hello-world: Could not process schema files in directory D:\Home\Workspaces\webservice\hello-world\src\main\resources -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using xs which is not defined in your schema. **xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** is missing
Try to replace:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/helloworld" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/helloworld"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

with:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/helloworld" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/helloworld"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```